# apt-get install rsyslog fails due to possible version mismatch: how to fix/report?

Tags: apt

I ran this code in a vagrant box (which hasn't changed in weeks) yesterday with no problem. Today it fails:

```
   add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable &&     apt-get update
 Contains the latest RSyslog V8-Stable packages and dependencies.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~adiscon/+archive/ubuntu/v8-stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxudrwwvh/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpxudrwwvh/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 5234BF2B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpxudrwwvh/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 5234BF2B: public key "Launchpad PPA for Adiscon" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK


root@hcf-vagrant:/home/vagrant# apt-get install rsyslog rsyslog-relp rsyslog-mmjsonparse rsyslog-gnutls -y 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rsyslog-gnutls : Depends: rsyslog (= 8.18.0-0adisconatrusty1) but 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
 rsyslog-mmjsonparse : Depends: rsyslog (= 8.18.0-0adisconatrusty1) but 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
 rsyslog-relp : Depends: rsyslog (= 8.18.0-0adisconatrusty1) but 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@hcf-vagrant:/home/vagrant#
```

Looking at https://launchpad.net/~adiscon/+archive/ubuntu/v8-stable I can see that the repo was updated around 2016-05-06 11:00:00 UTC. A coworker thinks the problem is that there's no `libfastjson` library in the repro for `ubuntu/trusty`, only for `xenial`.

I'm not the only one who ran into this today:

https://twitter.com/jaymzcampbell/status/728612402984521732

Anyone have a workaround? Would replacing `ppa:adiscon/v8-stable` with `ppa:adiscon/v7-stable` work (that's actually a cumbersome fix the way our build system is set up, but I'll give it a try)?

Comment: Could you please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` in a terminal and let us know the result?

Comment: Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

Comment: Bug reported at https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-pkg-ubuntu/issues/44